# Minor: Ads Display Page Title/Link

Tags: feature-request, design, community-promotion-ads

I just visited [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/195823), by clicking 'stats' on the bottom of an ad.

I noticed that the 'Return to Question' link is styled like a title.
It's styled the same as 'Top Questions' on the home screens of the Meta/Main site.

It is clickable, but because it doesn't look like a link, I didn't immediately want to.
Shouldn't it show 'Current Ads' or something similar, actually as a title? The Return to Question should be displayed elsewhere/styled differently.

As I've said in the title, it's minor; but I thought I'd mention it.

[image]

Comment: It takes you back to where the ads are defined. Not all of the ads in the question end up on this display page.

Comment: Ah. Without clicking the link, I hadn't realised. I clicked the 'stats' link from a question on the main site, so I assumed it would take me back there!

Comment: Not a bug, that's the standard behavior all across the site. For example [revisions page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/200407/revisions) also has "Return to Answer/Question"

Comment: Perhaps then the page needs more explanation? I didn't know about the meta thread, as I arrived at the page from the main site.